# java.nio.file.Path.contains(subPath)?

Tags: java, nio

I need to check whether a given path is a subpath anywhere within another path and was wondering whether there exists such a method already before writing my own.

Here is some code that may help to understand the problem:

```
Path someRealPath = Paths.get("/tmp/some/path/to/somewhere");
Path subpathToCheck = Paths.get("some/path");

// I am expecting something similar as follows:
someRealPath.contains(subPathToCheck) // should return true in this case
someRealPath.contains(Paths.get("some/to")) // should return false
```

I already saw `relativize`, but I don't think that's the easiest way to solve the problem. The simplest I came up with was `normalize().toString().contains(/* other normalized string path */)`. But maybe there is an easier way? Lots of methods inside `Paths` look as if this functionality must already be in there. Maybe I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

What I came up with is the following:

```
boolean containsSubPath(Path someRealPath, Path subPathToCheck) {
  return someRealPath.normalize()
                     .toString()
                     .contains(subPathToCheck.normalize()
                                             .toString());
}
```

This way I am able to just call:

```
containsSubPath(Paths.get("/tmp/some/path/to/somewhere"), Paths.get("some/path"));
```

As Thomas Kläger pointed out, this solution matches also paths, that are only substrings of a real path (which for my use case would also be ok).

Here is another solution that is probably more correct (for complete matching subpaths), but still not as short as I would like it to be (now corrected due to Kabhals input):

```
static boolean containsSubPath(Path realPath, Path subPath) {
  for (Path realPathSegment : realPath.normalize()) {
    if (containsSubPath(realPathSegment.iterator(), subPath.normalize().iterator())) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
private static boolean containsSubPath(Iterator<Path> realPathIterator, Iterator<Path> subPathIterator) {
  var hasEntries = realPathIterator.hasNext() && subPathIterator.hasNext();
  while (realPathIterator.hasNext() && subPathIterator.hasNext()) {
    Path realPathSegment = realPathIterator.next();
    Path subPathSegment = subPathIterator.next();
    if (!Objects.equals(realPathSegment, subPathSegment))
      return false;
  }
  return hasEntries;
}
```

Example calls with expected output:

```
containsSubPath(Paths.get("/tmp/some/path/to/somewhere"), Paths.get("some/path")) // true
containsSubPath(Paths.get("/tmp/some/path/to/somewhere"), Paths.get("me/pa")) // false
```

If you need to use it as `BinaryOperator` just use the method reference instead, i.e. `YourClass::containsSubPath`.

Comment: Not sure if your solution is correct. `containsSubPath.test(Paths.get("/tmp/some/path/to/somewhere"), Paths.get("me/pa"))` gives also true, but I would expect it to return false.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! for my use case it would be ok as I know the whole sub path that needs to be found and I also know that there do not exist similar partial subpaths ;-) however if there is a more complete (and correct) solution, which can handle complete subpaths, that would even be better. Played also around with `Path.subpath` combined with an `IntStream`, but that seems rather complicated for such an easy problem. Maybe `Path.normalize().iterator` is the easiest and most complete solution.

Comment: The algorithm is still not correct. The following test `containsSubPath.test(Paths.get("other/other/other/path"), Paths.get("other/other/path"))` returns mistakenly `false`

Comment: you are right, I didn't take into account same consecutive directory names. If a name matches it is tried to compare regardless of other paths matching... will try to adapt the answer to reflect that case. Meanwhile, if you already have a solution, feel free to add as an answer...

Comment: adapted (or better rewrote) the solution, which should now work as expected...